# scipy optimize SLSQP only takes last ineq constrant into account

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Let's say I have a portfolio with weights, sum = 1.
Then I want to define pockets (0, 1, 2) with some assets included in those pockets, and sum(weights_pocket_assets) < pocket_max_weight
On my UI, I have a 3 columns for each pocket, filled with 1 if asset is in pocket, 0 otherwise (this array is called 'pockets')

```
mask = list(map(int, pockets[0]))
print(pocket_max[0], mask)
constr0 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: pocket_max[0] - np.sum(np.ma.array(x, mask=np.logical_not(mask)))}

mask = list(map(int, pockets[1]))
print(pocket_max[1], mask)
constr1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: pocket_max[1] - np.sum(np.ma.array(x, mask=np.logical_not(mask)))}

mask = list(map(int, pockets[2]))
print(pocket_max[2], mask)
constr2 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: pocket_max[2] - np.sum(np.ma.array(x, mask=np.logical_not(mask)))}

constr = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1}, constr0, constr1, constr2]
print(constr)
```

gives as output:

```
0.04 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
0.08 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
0.05 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

[{'fun': <function Book.optimize.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000060CCD9AD90>, 'type': 'eq'}, 
{'fun': <function Book.optimize.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000060CCD9AD08>, 'type': 'ineq'},
{'fun': <function Book.optimize.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000060CCD9ABF8>, 'type': 'ineq'},
{'fun': <function Book.optimize.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000060CCD9AAE8>, 'type': 'ineq'}]
```

which seems correct.
Problem is optimize only with eq and last ineq (ie sum(w) = 1 and sum(w_pocket_2) = 0.05)
Also if I have only 2 pockets, it optimizes with last only.
For short, it only takes last ineq in optimization... don't know what's wrong.

EDIT:
if pockets are equals (ie, same components for each pocket, ie same mask) then all 3 'ineq' constraints are taken into account (ie the most constraining in fact, but no problem if it's the first 'ineq', the second or the third that is the most constraining)
as soon as pockets have not similar components (ex: we add a component for the second 'ineq'), only the last 'ineq' is taken by optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often, it was a problem with variable scope (odd stuff since variables were still defined, but overwritten. I did not investigate more to fully understand). The following code works as expected (all pockets constraints taken into account):

```
constr += ({'type': 'ineq',
            'fun': lambda x, mask, pocket_max, i: pocket_max[i] - np.sum(np.ma.array(x, mask=np.logical_not(mask))),
            'args': (mask, pocket_max, i )}, )
```